# Where is his name?

Tags: steganography

> that's just an Error Depiction. Don't Go around Jousting anyone For Internet silly Examples of doing it, -In fact i just want you to stay Around. don't be mean to others as Internal psychological Damage Happens to exist, invisible but
>   As real as the Devil's Existence

His name can be located above.

Big fan of the country. (But it is too cold for me, as I can't handle snow)

Big fan of his plays. (But as I needed to read some at school, it was really boring)

> Please mods, do not edit the blockquoted text, This one is a silly cipher, not a riddle, so the horrendous errors are part of it.

Do you know his name?

Comment: Should the title be 'What is his name'?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Where may be indication that we have to get information from within. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38110922#38110922

Comment: Is it a cipher or steganography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His name is:

> William Shakepseare.

In the block-quoted text:

> Take the capital letters (And the decimals and dash)
>  ED.DGJFIE -IA.IDHADE
>  Convert them to digits, A=0
>  43.369584 -80.837034
>
>  Put them into Google Maps

You will see a nice picture of:

> Shakespeare, Ontario, Canada
>  Canada's a little cold, I live here, but this specific location has enough lake effect that it doesn't get too cold, but the air is always damp, so frost is a big thing...

Comment: Ahhh I figured lat/long but left out . to fit it... nice job

Comment: @n_palum Yup.  Looks like Deusovi was on the right track but with the wrong letter index.  I didn't even see the chat transcript before.

Comment: Yeah, that's it :D